# Why is my CSS file blank when loading my webpage via IIS?

Tags: html, css, iis

EDIT: Problem turned out to go away when I changed the file to a HTML file instead of ASP. The CSS was actually fine. Strange, but thanks to all that helped...

I am trying to go through the 'CSS How To' tutorial on W3Schools.com, and can't get the HTML to pick up the CSS file (I think).

I have copied and pasted the code into default.asp and mystyle.css, and they are both in the same directory. I am running the webpage via IIS.

This is the HTML in the Default.asp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<style>
h1 {
  color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The style of this document is a combination of an external stylesheet, and internal style</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS in mystyle.css:

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

The header is orange as expected, but the `background-color` doesn't change.
I have tried this in FF/IE/Edge/Chrome, but none of them seem to pick up the CSS file.

I tried red as well in case lightblue didn't show properly. I have tried this via IIS on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194789/discussion-on-question-by-lars-panzerbjrn-why-is-my-css-file-blank-when-loading).

Comment: is your issue is resolved or not?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, Yes, sort of. I guess the question can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to post the correct solution and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per Jalpa's suggestion, I'll post an answer with what "fixed" it.
I changed the file to .html instead of .asp which caused it to work. I didn't realise that an ASP page needed something different from a HTML page in order to pick up the CSS file...